# How to get all files from a Bucket - IBM Cloud Object Storage?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I want to get all files that are in my bucket with python. I trying this way:

```
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config, ClientError

files = cos.Object(my_bucket_name).objects.all() # error here
```

But it shows this error:

```
ValueError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
Required parameter key not set
```

How do I get all objects/files from the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was doing it wrong, the correct way is like this:

```
files = cos.Bucket(bucket_name).objects.all()
```

Problem solved!